# Vaadin: How to set a partial value in the input field of a Combobox and trigger the popup to open?

Tags: combobox, vaadin

Vaadin V24, Java.

I'd like to programmatically set the text of a ComboBox (partial input) that's being used as a search field and then trigger it to do the search. This would be just as if the user was typing it themselves. I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this from the server-side.

My thought is something like this, where I set the value on the `<vaadin-combo-box>` and then trigger a key press event:

```
ComboBox<PojoClassHere> searchBox = new ComboBox<>();
...later in code...
searchBox.getElement().executeJs("this.setAttribute('value', '" + textValueToInsert + "'); this.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));");
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

According to this page, https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-web-components/24.2.1/#/elements/vaadin-combo-box, you can set the value on the `<vaadin-combo-box>` and it will propagate to internal components. The key press event, I would think, would trigger it to do the search and dropdown the list.

Comment: Can you also describe why you need to do this? Why you cannot set the ComboBox value is POJO reference?

Comment: I asked myself the same, but I think the goal here is to trigger the suggestion box with a (partial) match on the client side and make the user do actual selection. If that is not the case, I'd also suggest to add the actual reason/plan for this just to rule out an X-Y-problem etc.

Comment: The reasoning for this is that previous search terms are stored in local storage on the client. There is a button component next to the search box that brings up previous search terms in a dialog, when one is clicked, I'd like to feed that into the combobox and trigger the search as if the user typed them in.

Comment: Ok, that sounds a legit case, I wrote you answer and edited the question to reflect the context better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a common use case, thus there is no Java API for it. But this can be achieved by the following JavaScript call

```
comboBox.getElement().executeJs("""
    this.inputElement.value='Au';
    this.inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancellable: true}));
""");
```

Which will produce the following result in a ComboBox having list of country names:

[image]